# Word, Doubleword, Quadword

Tags: linux, assembly, x86

It's my second question, one after another. That's the problem with assembly (x86 - 32bit) too.

"Programming from the Ground Up" says that 4bytes are 32bits and that's a word.
But Intel's "Basic Architecture" guide says, that word is 16bits (2 bytes) and 4 bytes is a dualword. 
Memory uses 4bytes words, to get to another word I have to skip next 4 bytes, on each word I can make 4 offsets (0-3) to read a byte, so it's wrong with Intel's name, but this memory definition goes from Intel, so what's there bad?

And how to operate on words, dualword, quadwords in assembly? How to define the number as quadword?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your first question, the processor word size is a function of the architecture. Thus, a 32-processor has a 32-bit word. In software types, including assembly, usually there is need to identify the size unambigously, so word type for historical reasons is 16-bits. So probably both sources are correct, if you read them in context: the first one is referring to the processor word, while the Intel guide is referring to the word type.

Comment: And when I operate on bytes in Assemlby on linux's gcc I'm using 16bit word or 32? Suspect this second one...

Comment: @Vilo In x86 assembly a word/WORD/.word type should have 16-bits. [X86 Assembly/GAS Syntax](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/GAS_Syntax)

Comment: In x86, `word` _never_ refers to a theoretical 32 bit processor word.

Answer (score 1):

We've got different "word"s: program words, memory words, OS-specific words, architecture-specific words (program space word, flash word, eeprom word), even address words.

It's just a matter of convention what size the word `word` refers to.

I usually find the size of the word by looking at the number of hex digits the context is using to show them. Intel's most common type, 4 digits (0x0000), is two bytes.

And for further information, even `byte` is a convention. In many systems in the past bytes have been 7 or 9 bits. Most architectures nowadays have 8-bit bytes. The correct name for an always-8-bit structure is an `octet`.

Comment: It's too much to me for now :D I don't know all the conventions, so now I'll just jump with the bytes using suffixes and have to remember that stack is 16 or 32 bit to not waste the memory :P

Comment: So just stick to word == 16 bit. This is the convention used in x86 and x86_64.